# python bisect.insort(list, value)

Tags: python, list, module, insert, bisect

does this python module computes an ordered insert into a data structure or it inserts and then sort? been struggling with this kind of thing in python since developing an algorithm in which I have to keep in mind memmory issues thus need a way to insert into a list just in the right position, as it should be done in java using a linkedlist but not sure what to use and how.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This insert `value` in a `list` at the correct position, note that it assumes is already sorted. From the documentation:

> Insert x in a in sorted order. This is equivalent to
>   `a.insert(bisect.bisect_left(a, x, lo, hi), x)` assuming that a is
>   already sorted. Keep in mind that the O(log n) search is dominated by
>   the slow O(n) insertion step.

The last part refers to the fact that insertion on a Python list is `O(n)`. The search is done using [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

If you start from an empty list and repeatedly use this algorithm to insert the objects into a list, the final list will be sorted. This algorithm is known as [binary insertion sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-insertion-sort/). For example:

```
import bisect

l = [1, 3, 7, 5, 6, 4, 9, 8, 2]

result = []
for e in l:
    bisect.insort(result, e)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Note:** The complexity of this algorithm is `O(n*n)` given the `O(n)` insertion step.

Comment: so if i have kind of a frontier and want to insert objects of another class in the correct position depending on a random attribute that is generated, does this module help me out to insert it in the correct position? at the beggining the list is empty so if using this i guess it will always insert in the correct way without actually sorting the list but not sure do :/ that's why im asking for advice, ty.

Comment: @jupcan Basically yes, the array will remain sorted. I updated the answer.

Comment: thank u very much! and there is no better way to do smth similar right?

Comment: @jupcan you could insert at the end using `append` (the method from list) and then sort the list using as key your attribute.

Comment: but the complexity of that would be greater wouldn't it? have tried before and the time it takes for large amount of data grows exponentially